# Animate background image from bottom to top, continuous repeat jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

When you land on a page I'd like the background image to be focused on the bottom of the image and then pan up to the top of the image and then go back down and continuously repeat. I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://smmcnyc.com/work/apf/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/front-img2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#container {
    height: 100vh;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').animate({
        'background-position-x': '50%',
        'background-position-y': '0'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
    });
});
```

Why isn't this working? How do I get the process to cycle up and down continuously? Can I even use this code since Firefox does not support "background-position-x" but jQuery does not support "background-position" with .animate()?

JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bqc8o2hn/2/

Comment: I think you can do the same with CSS3 animation instead.

Comment: with **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, it is just one line of code: https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/bqc8o2hn/7/

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want? i did it using css transition.

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").toggleClass("to_top");
    window.setInterval(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("to_top");
    },4000);
});    

body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://smmcnyc.com/work/apf/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/front-img2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transition:all 2s;
}
#container {
    height: 100vh;
}
.to_top{
    background-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqc8o2hn/6/)

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://smmcnyc.com/work/apf/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/front-img2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
body.loaded {
    animation: bouncebg 5s ease;
}
@keyframes bouncebg {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 50% 100%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 50% 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bouncebg {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 50% 100%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 50% 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bouncebg {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 50% 100%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 50% 0;
    }
}
#container {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Updated JS Codes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Hope, this would help!

Comment: This works great until I check it in IE11! Any ideas why this wouldn't work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try using the `body.loaded {
    animation: bouncebg 5s linear;
}` . Please provide the exact result which you seeing in IE11. Updated fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bqc8o2hn/10/)